# omp for with collapse clause is not compiling

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmp

I am parallelizing with a parallel `for` construct in OpenMP.

In OpenMP specs, I can see:

```
void sub(float *a)
{
int i, j, k;
#pragma omp for collapse(2) private(i, k, j)
for (k=kl; k<=ku; k+=ks)
    for (j=jl; j<=ju; j+=js)
        for (i=il; i<=iu; i+=is)
            bar(a,i,j,k);
}
```

I've written code that I find quite similar, but it does not compile:

> unexpected token after collapse clause

```
#pragma omp for collapse(2)  
for(int i=0;i<N-m;i++)
    for(int k=0;k<m_ndim;k++)
        points_[i][k]=TRandom::randD(lower[k],upper[k]);
```

Why isn't it working?

Comment: what version of openmp do you have?

Comment: VS is still not up to date to the current OpenMP standard. Maybe you want to try gcc instead, which implements the current one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`collapse` is an OpenMP 3.0 pragma. The error message you received is usually due to a compiler that implements OpenMP 2.x only.